# Weird behaviour with constructors

Tags: javascript

Can someone please explain this behaviour to me.

First let's create a constructor and a new object using the constructor:

```
var MyConstructor = function() {};
var obj = new MyConstructor();
```

Everything is as expected:

```
console.log(obj.constructor === MyConstructor); //true
console.log(obj.__proto__ === MyConstructor.prototype); //true
```

Let's try again, but this time let's add a custom prototype to the constructor:

```
var MyConstructor2 = function() {};
var myProto = { fld: 'val' };
MyConstructor2.prototype = myProto;
var obj2 = new MyConstructor2();
```

Now things are not as I expect them to be:

```
console.log(obj2.constructor === MyConstructor2); //false?!?!
console.log(obj2.constructor === Object); //true, b-but i didnt use Object..
console.log(obj2.__proto__ === MyConstructor2.prototype); //true
```

Why is `obj2.constructor` referring to `Object` and not `MyConstructor2`?

--- edit1 ---

Just to clarify. If you create a new function:

```
var MyConstructor = function() {};
```

then Javascript implementation will also create a new object:

```
var temp = { constructor: MyConstructor };
```

and set it to:

```
MyConstructor.prototype = temp;
```

The thing to note here is that the temp object overwrites the `constructor` field from `Object.prototype` (and by default `Object.prototype.constructor === Object`).

So when I create a new object using the constructor:

```
var obj = new MyConstructor();
```

then the object inherits the constructor field which points to `MyConstructor`. In the second case there was no overwriting, so the second object inherited the constructor field directly from `Object.prototype`.

Comment: you should add a constructor property with value MyConstructor2 to the newly set prototype object (myProto)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each `Function` object has a `prototype` property whose "constructor" property is referencing the function. When you create a new prototype using the Object literal syntax, you are created a brand new object whose constructor is literally the `Object` function. You need to explicitly set the constructor property:

```
function MyConstructor2() {

}

MyConstructor2.prototype = {
    constructor: MyConstructor2
};
```